# What is the distributive reflection of the lattice of ideals of a ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, ideals, lattice-orders

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and let $L$ be the set of ideals of $A$, partially ordered by inclusion. $L$ is a complete lattice but is not distributive in general. For instance, in the polynomial ring $k [x, y]$:
$$((x) + (y)) \cap (x + y) = (x + y)$$
$$((x) \cap (x + y)) + ((y) \cap (x + y)) = (x (x + y), y (x + y))$$
On the other hand, sometimes $L$ is distributive – for instance, if $A$ is a principal ideal domain.

By general nonsense, there is a frame (= complete lattice in which binary meets distribute over arbitrary joins) $F$ and a "frame" homomorphism (= monotone map preserving finite meets and arbitrary joins) $L \to F$ such that every "frame" homomorphism from $L$ to a frame factors through $L \to F$ in a unique way. This is called the frame reflection of $L$.

**Question.** Is there a "nice" description of the frame reflection of $L$?

Again, by general nonsense, the "frame" homomorphism $L \to F$ is surjective and admits a right adjoint $F \to L$, which means we can think of $F$ as a certain subset of $L$ that is closed under arbitrary meets. In other words, $F$ is isomorphic to the poset of ideals of $A$ satisfying a certain condition – is there a "nice" description of that condition?

There is a well known frame of ideals associated with $A$, namely the frame of radical ideals of $A$, better known in its incarnation as the poset of open subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} A$. In general, $F$ is "larger" than the frame of radical ideals: for instance, if $A = \mathbb{Z}$. So $F$ corresponds to some kind of generalisation of radical ideal.

It may be worth pointing out that $A \mapsto F$ is probably not functorial. The obvious functor $A \mapsto L$ sends ring homomorphisms to monotone maps that preserve arbitrary joins, but binary meets may not be preserved. (This is basically because multiplication in the ring maps to ideal multiplication rather than ideal intersection. So we get a quantale homomorphism rather than a "frame" homomorphism – and taking the frame reflection of $L$ as a quantale yields the frame of radical ideals.)

Comment: What about the frame of subfunctors of the representable functor $\text{Hom}(A, -)$ (cosieves on $A$, or sieves on $\text{Spec } A$)? Every ideal gives a subfunctor $\text{Hom}(A/I, -)$. I have no idea if this is the distributive reflection, but it's at least a canonical frame you can write down.

Comment: Never mind, I guess the frame of subfunctors is enormous. Maybe the subfunctors which are Zariski sheaves or something like that is more tractable.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to express the frame reflection using Grothendieck topology machinery: it is the frame of closed sieves on the poset of ideals for the smallest Grothendieck topology that makes the joins that already exist into covering families. This usually fails to be subcanonical, and it isn’t very explicit...